# When setting up nodeos and cleos for the first time, do you have to load your private key in order to query your account info?

Tags: cleos

I just setup nodeos and cleos, but was unsure if I need to load my private keys to just view my balance. Can't I just run the cleos command to get my account balance without my private key?

Comment: you only need account name because balances are public. but if you're querying your own node, it needs to be synched

Comment: @confused00 consider writing this as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @AmiHeines thanks for the reminder; i haven't had the time to write proper answers lately. i'll write an answer eventually if no one else does